# Sentence embedding in keras

Tags: keras, lstm, keras-layer, word-embedding

I am trying a simple document classification using sentence embeddings in keras.

I know how to feed word vectors to a network, but I have problems using sentence embeddings. In my case, I have a simple representation of sentences (adding the word vectors along the axis, for example `np.sum(sequences, axis=0)`).

My question is, what should I replace the `Embedding` layer with in the code below to feed sentence embeddings instead?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(embedding_weights), len(embedding_weights[0]), weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True, 
input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=True))
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_SIZE, activation='relu'))
```

I've tried `Embedding` layer (without setting the weights) and `Input` layer but both gave errors.

Comment: Have you tried to feed it directly to the LSTM with the parameter `input_shape=(nr_sentences,embedding_dim)`? Have a look at the the very first example of the _Keras Recurrent Layers_ documentation.

Comment: `model = Sequential()`  `model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(len(labels), MAX_SENTENCE_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)))`  

`model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))`   

where `MAX_SENTENCE_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 65`  

 gives `Exception: Error when checking model input: expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 65)`

Comment: The error means, that you input data is not correctly shaped. I assume that you need the the following dimension for your task: `(no_documents, max_nr_sentences_per_doc, sentence_embedding_dim)`
Otherwise please give more information about the task you want to achieve and your input/output data.